# What is the best way to restrict method access at compile time?

Tags: c#, .net, resharper, roslyn

Let's say I have a Manager class

```
public class Manager {
   public Item Create() {
      ...
      return new Item(...);
   }
}
```

and I have an Item class:

```
public class Item {
   [AllowCallBy(typeof(Manager))]
   public Item(...) {
   }
   ...
}
```

Now, I would like to use the easiest and most straightforward way to analyze the attributes like `AllowCallBy` at compile time and display errors or warnings. If, in this particular case, a class other than Manager class tries to instantiate `Item` with `new Item(...)` I would like to display something like "don't instantiate Item class directly, call Manager.Create(...) instead".

I suppose that at least one of the systems: Roslyn, ReSharper, PostSharp or maybe something else would allow me to do it or something that is very close to what I'm trying to achieve. Could somebody give an example of what to use and how to use it?

Comment: This sounds like a code smell, I am not sure how you would achieve something like this at compile time, but you should reconsider your design. May be create a static method  or a constructor in Item class which takes a parameter of type Manager, to make sure that each item is related to a manager or something one these lines...

Comment: I believe you can write an analyzer with Roslyn that warns you, yeah. If you change the severity to Error I suppose it would also prevent building the application.

Comment: The problem is there would be nothing to stop another developer that disagrees with your premise from just removing this warning. What I imagine would be better would be either removing specific requirements from the `Item` class, making an `Item` constructor with a manager parameter, or adding more detail to your question that better describes the *problem you are trying to solve*

Comment: Of course, I gave a simplified example and I have more different ones but with the same requirements - to warn other developers working on the same library that certain method or property should not be called or set directly but only via other classes which know how to initialize and set it right. In this particular case Manager knows how to initialize the Item but Item does not use Manager inside and I believe it should not store a reference to Manager.

Comment: I don't think it should either, but this seems like an [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well color me surprised.  [PostSharp lets you do exactly what you're looking for](http://doc.postsharp.net/control-visibility#types).  In a nutshell, you'd use the `ComponentInternalAttribute` to control visibility of a type:

```
public class Item {
   [ComponentInternal(typeof(Manager))]
   public Item(...) {
   }
   ...
}
```

According to their documentation linked above, attempting to invoke `Item`'s constructor outside of `Manager` will yield a compile-time warning:

> Method Item.ctor cannot be referenced from *[some other method]* because of the [ComponentInternal] constraint.

You can make it an error by changing the severity level of the attribute:

```
public class Item {
   [ComponentInternal(typeof(Manager), Severity = SeverityType.Error)]
   public Item(...) {
   }
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely a [code smell](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CodeSmell) as @Habib mentions (can someone link to a specific one?), but without a more complete example it's difficult to offer alternatives beyond what has already been suggested in comments.  I'd encourage you to expand your sample or rethink your design.

---

However, I can present one option that I've used in the past though not for this purpose.  You could mark `Item`'s constructor as [`Obsolete`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute.aspx):

```
public class Item {
   [Obsolete("Don't instantiate Item class directly, call Manager.Create(...) instead")]
   public Item(...) {
   }
   ...
}
```

Then in your `Manager` class, you'd specifically ignore this warning where you invoke the constructor:

```
public class Manager {
   public Item Create() {
      ...
#pragma warning disable 618
      return new Item(...);
#pragma warning restore 618
   }
}
```

This way, whenever someone tries to create their own `Item` elsewhere in the code, they'll get a [level 2 CS0618 warning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5ye6x1e.aspx) indicating that they *should not* use the method (note that I didn't say *cannot*) with exactly the text entered in the attribute.  If [warnings as errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/406xhdz3.aspx) is enabled (for all warnings or just this one), then it will be a compile error as you originally wanted.

Be aware, nothing prevents others from adding these `pragma` statements to get around the error.  However, with this method the developer can't say they didn't know they weren't supposed to use the constructor.

Comment: I thought about it. The only thing I didn't like about is that the ObsoleteAttribute is used in a way it is not supposed to. But in general, probably it is the easiest solution. Still, I hope that there is a cleaner one with one of the mentioned systems.

Answer (score 0):

There are way better ways to achieve your goal than your current approach, **given that you can actually change that code**.

You could for example mark the contructor of Item class as private and add a static factory method to Item class which would be responsible for creating an instance of the class.

Another way is to move Item class to another assembly, mark its constructor as internal and implement another class (a factory) which would be responsible for creating different Item objects. Then you class is visible from other assemblies, but it cannot be directly instantiated, so forces the code user to use provided factory.

Comment: All this assumes that the code can be changed though. It might very well be a legacy design issue that, for good reasons, can't just be adapted. That's where a Roslyn diagnostic would be appropriate: to prevent the same problem from occurring again before the team finds the time to fix it.

Comment: The OP did not explicitly mention not being able to change the current code so I came up with that answer. Should I delete it then?

Comment: That's why I specifically emphasized on "warn people working on the same library". That is why making them internal won't work. Marking the constructor with private and creating a static method won't work either because an instance of Manager has certain fields which are used in initialization of Item. So the Item cannot correctly create itself. Only Manager can do it.

Comment: @AndrewB: no, not necessary to delete it. It is a correct answer in certain situations after all -- I'm merely adding that in certain other scenarios it might not be applicable.